# How to find out which files changed by PhysicalFileProvider in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to know How to find out which files changed by PhysicalFileProvider in .NET Core?

```cs
var watcher = new PhysicalFileProvider("../.");
var changeToken = watcher.Watch("*.*");
```

I need some results like

```
abc.txt => Deleted
xyz.mp3 => Added
opq.png => Changed
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Probably. Did you try anything? Apparently not.

Comment: @IanKemp I used `RegisterChangeCallback` but `state` is null. All changes discard except the first one.

Comment: Hi @HF_67 you should get a new `IChangeToken` after each change.

Comment: Afaik there is no way to know what happend to the file you only know it `changed` in some way. Consider using a `FileSystemWatcher` if you want to know exactly what happend.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.0#examples) sounds like what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to get this same information from the token state as well but have had no luck finding anything in the token that indicates what has changed.  My implementation is for a linux container where networked file shares need to be monitored for changes thus the `FileSystemWatcher` will not suffice so I am forced to use the `PhysicalFileProvider` class. (see [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7576))

My suggestion would be to use the `FileSystemWatcher` if that implementation will work for your situation.

If that will not work, make use of the `PhysicalFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents()` method and store the state of the directory or file to be watched.  When the token indicates a change has happened, compare the stored state with the current state of the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `FileSystemWatcher` does not trigger an event on the Docker w/ NFS scenario. The interesting thing is `PhysicalFileProvider` uses `FileSystemWatcher` as an underlying system. Anyway, if you want to use a dirty workaround, here it is.

```cs
    private IChangeToken _fileChangeToken;
    private PhysicalFileProvider _fileProvider;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> _files = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>();

    public void DoWork()
    {
        _fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"/mnt/uploads"); // e.g. C:\temp
        WatchForFileChanges();
    }

    private void WatchForFileChanges()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(DirectoryToWatch, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (_files.TryGetValue(file, out DateTime existingTime))
            {
                _files.TryUpdate(file, File.GetLastWriteTime(file), existingTime);
            }
            else
            {
                if (File.Exists(file))
                {
                    _files.TryAdd(file, File.GetLastWriteTime(file));
                }
            }
        }
        _fileChangeToken = _fileProvider.Watch("**/*.*");
        _fileChangeToken.RegisterChangeCallback(Notify, default);
    }

    private void Notify(object state)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("File activity detected.");
        WatchForFileChanges();
    }
```